# Why is the Pinnable<T> class in C# 7.2 defined the way it is?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, cil, c#-7.2

I'm aware that `Pinnable<T>` is an internal class used by the methods in the new `Unsafe` class, and it's not meant to be used anywhere else other than in that class. This question is not about something practical, but it's just to understand why it's been designed like this and to learn a bit more about the language and its various "tricks" like this one.

As a recap, the `Pinnable<T>` class is defined [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/ccc44b7b2e9145251e2ca98bbe0936938ed94379/src/System.Memory/src/System/Pinnable.cs), and it looks like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal sealed class Pinnable<T>
{
    public T Data;
}
```

And it's mainly used in the `Span<T>.DangerousCreate` method, [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Memory/src/System/Span.cs#L109):

```
public static Span<T> DangerousCreate(object obj, ref T objectData, int length)
{
    Pinnable<T> pinnable = Unsafe.As<Pinnable<T>>(obj);
    IntPtr byteOffset = Unsafe.ByteOffset<T>(ref pinnable.Data, ref objectData);
    return new Span<T>(pinnable, byteOffset, length);
}
```

The reason for `Pinnable<T>` being that it's used to keep track of the original object, in case the `Span<T>` instance was created by one (instead of a native pointer).

1. Given that reference type doesn't matter when pinning a reference (fixing both a `ref T` and `Unsafe.As<T, byte>(ref T)` works the same), is there a specific reason why the `Pinnable<T>` class was made generic? The original design in DotNetCross [here](https://github.com/DotNetCross/Memory.Unsafe/blob/ec4ba75ac9f69d08a05b33d423cd633a1a65f849/README.md) in fact had a `Pinnable` class with just a single `byte` field, and it worked just the same. Is there any reason why using a generic class in this case would be an advantage, other than avoiding to cast the reference time when writing/reading/returning it?
2. Is there any other way, other than this unsafe-cast done with `Unsafe.As`, to get a reference to an object (I mean a reference to the object contents, otherwise it'd be the same as any variable of a class type)? I mean, any way to get a reference (which should basically have the same address of the actual object variable in the first place, right?) to an object without having to pass through some custom defined secondary class.

Comment: `Pinnable<T>` is a class (reference type) for which `LayoutKind.Auto` is used by default. `Sequential` is used by default for value types (structs). That is a reason to specify layout for `Pinnable<T>`. See the Remarks sections in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind?view=netstandard-2.0).

Comment: @YohDeadfall Thanks, I hadn't noticed that detail about classes using that attribute! I've edited the question and added this info to the 2nd point. I'm not entirely sure about why this attribute is needed, since a `Span<T>` isn't explicitly passed to unmanaged code (I think, wouldn't you just fix it, get a pointer and pass that instead?), but at least that attribute makes sense now 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the *Struct* in `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` doesn't mean that it is only valid for structs, it means the layout of the actual structure of the fields in memory, be it in a class or in a value type. This controls the *actual* runtime layout of the data, not just how the type would marshal to unmanaged code. The *Sequential* is important because without it, the runtime is pretty much free to store the memory however it sees fit, which means that *Data* may have some padding before it.

1. From what I understand about the implementation, the reason for *Pinnable* is to allow creating an instance of *Span* to a memory that may be moved by the GC, without having to pin the object first. If you don't use actual pointers and just references, nothing at all will need to be pinned.

   I have noticed that it was introduced in a commit with a description saying it made *Span* more "portable" (a bold word for something that does a lot of unsafe things). I can't think of any other reason than something related to alignment for why it is generic. I suppose representing a `T` in terms of an offset from another `T` is better than as an offset from a `byte`. It may happen that the type of the first field may play a role in its actual address, even if the type was marked with *LayoutKind.Sequential*.
2. A reference to an object is different from an interior reference to an object (a reference to its data). It is implementation defined, but in .NET Framework, an instance of any class (or a boxed value type) starts with a header consisting of a sync block (for `lock`) and a pointer to the method table, a.k.a. the type of the object. On 32-bit, the header is 8 bytes, but the actual pointer points to the pointer to the method table (for performance reasons, getting the type happens more often than locking an object).

   One but not portable way of getting the pointer to the start of the data is therefore casting the object reference to a pointer and adding 4 bytes to it. There the first field should start.

   Another way I can think of is utilising *[GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.addrofpinnedobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)*. It is commonly used for accessing array or string data, but it works for other objects:

   ```
   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
   class Obj
   {
       public int A;
   }

   var obj = new Obj();
   var gc = GCHandle.Alloc(obj, GCHandleType.Pinned);
   IntPtr interior = gc.AddrOfPinnedObject();
   Marshal.WriteInt32(interior, 0, 16);
   Console.WriteLine(obj.A);
   ```

   I think this actually is quite portable, but still needs to pin the object (there is *InternalAddrOfPinnedObject* defined in *GCHandle*, but even if that doesn't check whether the handle is actually pinned, the returned value may not be valid if it was used on a non-pinned object).

   Still, the technique *Span* uses seems like the most portable way of doing that, since a lot of the underlying work is done in pure CIL (like reference arithmetics).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, even if that generic bit of the `Pinned<T>` class is still not 100% clear, all the rest makes much more sense now, cheers! 